# Error while deploying webservice. Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding

Tags: web-services, wcf, web-config, iis-7.5

I have been trying to deploy a simple Sync Service in .NET 3.5 in a production IIS server (Made it using the WCF Service Library of VS2008). While deploying and testing it, it has thrown the following error:

"Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]."

And this is the web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
            <add prefix="http://194.165.0.8:80/"/>
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration">
        <security mode="None">
        </security>
    </binding>       
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MobileSyncServiceLibrary.AdventureWorksSyncService" behaviorConfiguration="MobileSyncServiceLibrary.AdventureWorksSyncServiceBehavior">
             <endpoint  address="http://194.165.0.8:80/PruebaWS/MobileSyncServiceLibrary.AdventureWorksSyncService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="MobileSyncServiceLibrary.IAdventureWorksSyncContract" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfiguration"/>
             <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MobileSyncServiceLibrary.AdventureWorksSyncServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <remove value="Default.htm" />
                <remove value="Default.asp" />
                <remove value="index.htm" />
                <remove value="index.html" />
                <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
                <remove value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="MobileSyncServiceLibrary.AdventureWorksSyncService.svc" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
```

I have already done the solution pointed out in most posts about this question:

**Setting security mode=None**

**Setting httpsGetEnabled="false"**

All answers that I have seen, point to this two settings, but I have not been able to fix the error on the configuration.

Any ideas on what Im missing or what do i need to change? This is the current exception the service is throwing.

> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/PruebaWS/MobileSyncServiceLibrary.AdventureWorksSyncService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]..]
>      System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +594083
>      System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +238
>      System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +327
>      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +142
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +92

This are the current bindings on the site.

[image]

Comment: baseAddress="http://xxx.xxx.x.x/xxxxx/,can you replace this dummy IP's with some real numbers.

Comment: @Hameed done as you requested

Comment: You must use baseaddress prefix  filters if you are  hosting the wcf service in IIS.But I dont see any .svc service and also IIS doesnt support net.tcp binding.Can you check once again?

Comment: Deleted the net.tcp filter. It had a multiple binding exception before this one and i just pasted the answer. It is not needed.
Also added the default document section so show that is indeed pointing to a svc. 
Added too the current exception that IIS is throwing.

Comment: Edited to clean up the xml and eliminate unnecessary code

Comment: One more thing to check is iis, whether is it configured to accept http!? Reset check its default binding.

Comment: It is configured to accept http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the solution. I misread the multiple binding solution.

I read the following section as telling the site to which binding i was pointing the service.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
            <add prefix="http://194.165.0.8:80/"/>
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

When it is the exact opposite according to this answser.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/03687d4d-87dd-44b3-b945-05787ea93bd0/could-not-find-a-base-address-that-matches-scheme-http-for-the-endpoint-with-binding?forum=wcf

I was causing the problem, the service was being redirected to the https binding

So i changed the prefix to https://194.165.0.8:443 to filter out the https and send it to the http connection.